# Determine the given integral of differential binomial

Tags: indefinite-integrals

I need solve the given integral:
$$\int\sqrt[4]{4x-x^4}dx$$
My attemp:
$$\int\sqrt[4]{4x-x^4}dx=\int x^{\frac{1}{4}}(-x^3+4)^{\frac{1}{4}}dx$$
$p=\frac{1}{4}, q=4, r=\frac{1}{4}, s=2.$
$\frac{p+1}{q}, and \frac{p+1}{q}+r$ is not integer.
I have treated it as the integral of the binomial differential, but neither of the two conditions is fulfilled, so I don't know how to proceed, can anyone help me

Comment: The first step seems to add a power of $x$ inside the root...  Shouldn't it be $-x^3$?